# Finding out whether a string is numeric or not

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsstring

How can we check if a string is made up of numbers only. I am taking out a substring from a string and want to check if it is a numeric substring or not.

```
NSString *newString = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,3)];
```

Answer (score 246, accepted):

Here's one way that doesn't rely on the limited precision of attempting to parse the string as a number:

```
NSCharacterSet* notDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
if ([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound)
{
    // newString consists only of the digits 0 through 9
}
```

See [`+[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/decimalDigitCharacterSet) and [`-[NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfCharacterFromSet:).

Comment: this is true for @"231.123" so: // newString consists only of the digits 0 through 9 and the `.` character

Comment: NSMutableCharacterSet *digitsAndDots = [NSMutableCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
[digitsAndDots addCharactersInString:@"."];
NSCharacterSet *notDigitsNorDots = [digitsAndDots invertedSet];
//also, thanx for bringing in "invertedSet". I didn't know about its existence

Comment: Since you've got a mutable set there anyway, you could just call the 'invert' method on it rather than making a whole new set.

Comment: note: this method considers @"" to be a number; if applicable, you may need to also check for [newString lenght] > 0. please let me know if i'm wrong.

Comment: @NicolasTyler Are you sure? This is only working for whole numbers in my case. For example 85, 342 and 2134 all work fine, but 234.525 does not.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff It seems this is something that has changed in IOS. This can be used instead to be sure: `[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet]] `

Comment: @NicolasTyler interesting but does that cover all locals though? Like don't some use a comma instead of a dot?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff At the time when I did this 3 years ago the character set included `.` That doesnt seem to be the case anymore. I never tested if commas were included on other locals. But using `characterSetWithCharactersInString` could be used with any characters, if you are worried.

Comment: Why is [this page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscharacterset/1855954-decimaldigitcharacterset?language=objc) saying it's available from iOS 10+ if this answer in from 2011?

Comment: Why not just `NSCharacterSet *areDigits = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]` and then test for `!= NSNotFound`?

Comment: @Jeff You'd encounter false positives for strings that contain numerical characters, but do not represent numerical values, such as`g2g`

Comment: invertedSet
What is the cost of that operation? It should be a huge NSCharacterSet.

Comment: @KMGorbunov I don't think that NSCharacterSet is actually storing a backing set that contains every single character in the set. I suspect `invertedSet` is returning a class that wraps the set it was created form, and returns the opposite value for all queries. But I don't know for certain.

Comment: This solution will accept a variety of likely-unexpected strings: ``, ``, `१२३`, `١٢٣`, and `১২৩`, to name a few. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53926300/1292061), among others, addresses this issue.

Answer (score 35):

I'd suggest using the `numberFromString:` method from the [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, as if the number is not valid, it will return nil; otherwise, it will return you an NSNumber.

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
BOOL isDecimal = [nf numberFromString:newString] != nil;
```

Comment: Are you sure it won't return a valid number e.g. for @"124sbd"?

Comment: No, both NSNumberFormatter and NSScanner would return `NO` for your string. Also worth knowing: they also return `YES` for numbers padded with whitespace. Btw, I just added some actual code snippet to your answer, hope you don't mind.

Comment: NSScanner should return 'YES' for that string, per the documentation, having found "a valid integer representation". Furthermore, it did exactly that in a test on iOS 4.3.2. However, NSNumberFormatter did return nil.

Comment: This doesn't catch '.' which is a requirement for me. Answer from @John Calsbeek worked nicely.

Comment: What happens for a string with hundreds of characters all digits? Is there a limit to the NSNumber created?

Comment: the best answer is the scanner (see Regexident's answer), it can work for numeric strings too (the formatter didn't work for numbers like -1.2 for me)

Answer (score 12):

Validate by regular expression, by pattern `"^[0-9]+$"`, with following method `-validateString:withPattern:`.

```
[self validateString:"12345" withPattern:"^[0-9]+$"];
```

1. If "123.123" is considered

   - With pattern `"^[0-9]+(.{1}[0-9]+)?$"`
2. If exactly 4 digit numbers, without `"."`.

   - With pattern `"^[0-9]{4}$"`.
3. If digit numbers without `"."`, and the length is between 2 ~ 5.

   - With pattern `"^[0-9]{2,5}$"`.
4. With minus sign: `"^-?\d+$"`

The regular expression can be checked in [the online web site](https://regex101.com).

The helper function is as following.

```
// Validate the input string with the given pattern and
// return the result as a boolean
- (BOOL)validateString:(NSString *)string withPattern:(NSString *)pattern
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

    NSAssert(regex, @"Unable to create regular expression");

    NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
    NSRange matchRange = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:textRange];

    BOOL didValidate = NO;

    // Did we find a matching range
    if (matchRange.location != NSNotFound)
        didValidate = YES;

    return didValidate;
}
```

---

#### Swift 3 version:

Test in playground.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

func validate(_ str: String, pattern: String) -> Bool {
    if let range = str.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) {
        let result = str.substring(with: range)
        print(result)
        return true
    }
    return false
}

let a = validate("123", pattern: "^-?[0-9]+")
print(a)
```

Comment: I tried like this for Swift 3. ```func numberOnly(string: String) -> Int {
    let expression = ""
    let regex = NSRegularExpression.init(pattern: expression, options: .caseInsensitive)
    let numberOfMatches = regex.numberOfMatches(in: string, options: .reportProgress, range: NSRange.init(location: 0, length: string.characters.count))
    if numberOfMatches == 0 {
        return Int(string)!
    }
    return 0
}```
And I got error `Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).`

Comment: I don't know that correct one for swift 3. Correct me if I wrong.

Comment: How about just `return matchRange.location != NSNotFound;`

Comment: what about the minus sign?

Comment: @Thomas With `^-?\d+$`, I verified it on the site: https://regex101.com

Answer (score 9):

You could create an NSScanner and simply scan the string:

```
NSDecimal decimalValue;
NSScanner *sc = [NSScanner scannerWithString:newString];
[sc scanDecimal:&decimalValue];
BOOL isDecimal = [sc isAtEnd];
```

Check out [NSScanner's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanDecimal:) for more methods to choose from.

Comment: Wouldn't that just tell you whether at least the first character is numeric?

Comment: My bad. Forgot the final call to `isAtEnd`.

Answer (score 7):

I think the easiest way to check that every character within a given string is numeric is probably:

```
NSString *trimmedString = [newString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]];

if([trimmedString length])
{
    NSLog(@"some characters outside of the decimal character set found");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"all characters were in the decimal character set");
}
```

Use one of the other NSCharacterSet factory methods if you want complete control over acceptable characters.

Comment: I like this way. Although it doesn't seem very clean, it's a very easy and core foundation-friendly way of checking if there are "non-digits" in a NSString. + I think that it's much faster than any other robot-based ways ( although we're probably not looking much at performance here ).

Comment: I believe that stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet only trims the begin and end of the String

Comment: @BrodyRobertson: it does. Which matters not in the slightest for this answer. What example do you think this test would fail for?

Comment: @Tommy, After reevaluating I understand your answer and it is valid and will upvote but you need you to edit to allow me to revote

Answer (score 7):

Swift 3 solution if need to verify that the string has only digits:

```
CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: myString))
```

Comment: Clean and nice, best solution. I like that this does not do unnecessary `.inverted` and other actions.

Comment: Super clean solution, really like it !

Answer (score 6):

This original question was about Objective-C, but it was also posted years before Swift was announced. So, if you're coming here from Google and are looking for a solution that uses Swift, here  you go:

```
let testString = "12345"
let badCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet

if testString.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(badCharacters) == nil {
    print("Test string was a number")
} else {
    print("Test string contained non-digit characters.")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

to be clear, this functions for integers in strings.

heres a little helper category based off of John's answer above:

in .h file

```
@interface NSString (NumberChecking)

+(bool)isNumber:(NSString *)string;

@end
```

in .m file

```
#import "NSString+NumberChecking.h"

@implementation NSString (NumberChecking)

+(bool)isNumber {
    if([self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]].location == NSNotFound) {
        return YES;
    }else {
        return NO;
    }
}

@end
```

usage:

```
#import "NSString+NumberChecking.h"

if([someString isNumber]) {
    NSLog(@"is a number");
}else {
    NSLog(@"not a number");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3 solution could be like:

```
extension String {

    var doubleValue:Double? {
        return NumberFormatter().number(from:self)?.doubleValue
    }

    var integerValue:Int? {
        return NumberFormatter().number(from:self)?.intValue
    }

    var isNumber:Bool {
        get {
            let badCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
            return (self.rangeOfCharacter(from: badCharacters) == nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An extension of  ***@John Calsbeek***'s answer, and clarification of ***@Jeff*** and ***@gyratory circus***'s comments.

```
+ (BOOL)doesContainDigitsOnly:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *nonDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];

    BOOL containsDigitsOnly = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonDigits].location == NSNotFound;

    return containsDigitsOnly;
}

+ (BOOL)doesContainNonDigitsOnly:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *digits = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];

    BOOL containsNonDigitsOnly = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:digits].location == NSNotFound;

    return containsNonDigitsOnly;
}
```

The following can be added as category methods for **`NSString`**

```
- (BOOL)doesContainDigitsOnly
{
    NSCharacterSet *nonDigits = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];

    BOOL containsDigitsOnly = [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonDigits].location == NSNotFound;

    return containsDigitsOnly;
}

- (BOOL)doesContainNonDigitsOnly
{
    NSCharacterSet *digits = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];

    BOOL containsNonDigitsOnly = [self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:digits].location == NSNotFound;

    return containsNonDigitsOnly;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[John Calsbeek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6091456/1292061) is nearly correct but omits some Unicode edge cases.

Per the [documentation for `decimalDigitCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscharacterset/1408239-decimaldigitcharacterset?language=objc), that set includes all characters categorized by Unicode as `Nd`. Thus their answer will accept, among others:

- `१` (U+0967 DEVANAGARI DIGIT ONE)
- `᠑` (U+1811 MONGOLIAN DIGIT ONE)
- (U+1D7D9 MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK DIGIT ONE)

While in some sense this is correct — each character in `Nd` does map to a decimal digit — it's almost certainly not what the asker expected. As of this writing there are [610 code points categorized as `Nd`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Nd), only ten of which are the expected characters `0` (U+0030) through `9` (U+0039).

To fix the issue, simply specify exactly those characters that are acceptable:

```
NSCharacterSet* notDigits = 
    [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"] invertedSet];
if ([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:notDigits].location == NSNotFound)
{
    // newString consists only of the digits 0 through 9
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
- (BOOL)isValidNumber:(NSString*)text regex:(NSString*)regex {
    @try {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
        return [predicate evaluateWithObject:text];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        assert(false); 
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
BOOL isValid = [self isValidNumber:@"1234" regex:@"^[0-9]+$"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Test if a string is a number Might be Helpful

```
int i = [@"12.3" rangeOfCharacterFromSet: [ [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet] ].location;

if (i == NSNotFound) {
     //is a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift extension :

```
extension NSString {
func isNumString() -> Bool {
    let numbers = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789.").invertedSet
    let range = self.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(numbers).location
    if range == NSNotFound {
        return true
    }
    return false
}  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3**

```
var onlyDigits: CharacterSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
if testString.rangeOfCharacter(from: onlyDigits) == nil {
  // String only consist digits 0-9
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have digits that are from [mixed languages](https://www.omniglot.com/language/numerals.htm), that use (or don't) the 0-9 digits formats, you will need to run a regex that will look for any number, next thing is to convert all digits to be 0-9 format (if you need the actual value):

```
// Will look for any language digits
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^[:digit:]]", options: .caseInsensitive)
let digitsString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: string,
                                                         options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                         range: NSMakeRange(0, string.count), withTemplate: "")
// Converting the digits to be 0-9 format
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "EN")
let finalValue = numberFormatter.number(from: digitsString)

if let finalValue = finalValue {
  let actualValue = finalValue.doubleValue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most reliable way is trying to cast as `Double`, if the result is `nil` - it can't be formed into a legit number.

```swift
let strings = ["test", "123", "123.2", "-123", "123-3", "123..22", ".02"]
let validNumbers = strings.compactMap(Double.init)

print(validNumbers)
// prints [123.0, 123.2, -123.0, 0.02]
```

More info in the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2926277-init

Answer (score 0):

Simple wrote the string extension:

```
extension String {
    var isNumeric: Bool {
        return self.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C solution:

`[NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet isSupersetOfSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:field1]]`