# I want to check that input string is number in ios

Tags: ios

I want to check that input string is number, is there any way?
Basically strings are recieved from text field so need to check that whether the string in number or not.

Comment: @ChinttuRoxeNRamani No, this is iOS, not java

Comment: Iam talking about IOS my frnd

Comment: Sorry i copied different link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many solutions discussed in StackOverflow, take a look at:

[Finding out whether a string is numeric or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091414/finding-out-whether-a-string-is-numeric-or-not)

Comment: Cite from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238221/checking-if-nsstring-is-integer
  "does not check if the string contains only a valid number. It succeeds also for "123abc". " –  Martin R Sep 2 '12 at 18:11

Comment: Hermang:  the result is an NSDecimal. The best solution is the one of John Calsbeek in posted link.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *yourString = @"...";
 [yourString doubleValue] / [yourString floatValue] - this function will return the following:
```

The floating-point value of the receiver’s text as a double. Returns HUGE_VAL or –HUGE_VAL on overflow, 0.0 on underflow. Returns 0.0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid text representation of a floating-point number.

you can change the keyboard input type of the text field and then you make sure that the input is valid:
     yourTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;